# ¿Cómo podemos arreglar el tag javascript?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hace un tiempo vengo intentando seguir la etiqueta `javascript`, el problema es que me interesa responder cuestiones sobre el lenguaje, pero la etiqueta se usa para muchas preguntas en las que el lenguaje no es central.

Todas las preguntas sobre Angular, jQuery, nodejs, manipulación del DOM y web en general incluyen la etiqueta javascript por lo que la etiqueta pierde especificidad.

#### Aclaración

Un problema análogo sería el que ocurriría si todas las preguntas sobre un lenguaje orientado a objetos fueran etiquetadas con `[POO]`, en ese caso 
tendríamos más de 1000 preguntas con dicho tag y sería muy difícil encontrar preguntas *sobre la orientación a objetos*.

Un problema análogo ocurre con las etiquetas `[java]` y `[android]`, ya que uno implica al otro, pero en algunos casos el lenguaje es importante, mientras que otros casos es secundario.

---

Algunos ejemplos:

- [¿Cómo generar IDs con formato en Django?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7871/c%C3%B3mo-generar-ids-con-formato-en-django)

  La pregunta en realidad es si crear el id en el lado del servidor o en el "lado del cliente". El **lado del cliente** en este caso está etiquetado como "javascript".
- [Como puedo crear base de datos localStorage en apache cordova](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7851/como-puedo-crear-base-de-datos-localstorage-en-apache-cordova)

  En esta pregunta, el lenguaje de programación es secundario, la pregunta hace referencia principalmente a html5 y localStorage.
- [¿Cómo poner un botón en el titlebar de un grid en SENCHA TOUCH 2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7892/como-poner-un-boton-en-el-titlebar-de-un-grid-en-sencha-touch-2)

  En este caso, la pregunta es puntualmente sobre el framework, el lenguaje es circunstancial.

Comment: Cosiderando lo menscionado en la [respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/551/65) de @Carlos_Muñoz, en las primeras dos preguntas no se incluye código así que la justificación de usar [tag:javascript] por el resaltador de sintaxis no aplica. La tercera si tiene código.

Answer (score 6):

No solo pasa con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) sino con otras etiquetas de algún lenguaje de programación.

Las etiquetas de lenguaje de programación también sirven además para indicarle al *syntax highlighter* como debe formatear el código, por lo que está bien clasificar las preguntas como [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) y algún framework en específico

Además hay personas que pueden responder preguntas relacionadas con JavaScript y muchos frameworks relacionados, a los que sí les interesaría revisar preguntas relacionadas al lenguaje sin importar el framework al que se use.

En caso que querer hacer una búsqueda de aquellas preguntas etiquetadas con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) pero excluyendo las de [jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) y las de [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) por ejemplo puedes utilizar algunos operadores avanzados de búsqueda como:

```
[javascript] -[jquery] -[angularjs]
```

Ejemplo: [Preguntas "javascript -jquery -angularjs" más votadas - Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery+-angularjs?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

El `-` delante del tag `[jquery]` y `[angularjs]` indica que queremos excluir esta etiqueta.

Mas información sobre la búsqueda avanzada: [¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Hacer la búsqueda atendiendo a una falencia en las etiquetas no soluciona el problema con las etiquetas.

Comment: @eloyesp Esa búsqueda la puedes guardar con un marcador y usarla cuando quieras. Si una pregunta es especifica para un framework se puede editar y quitar la etiqueta. Creo que  es lo único que se puede  al respecto, respetando la intención del OP. Si yo pongo un tag `javascript` en mi pregunta porque tengo código en ese lenguaje no me gustaría que la quitaran, eso sería una edición dañina porque mi pregunta **si** se relaciona con javascript. Crear otra etiqueta sólo crea otro problema ya que es poco probable que los usuarios entiendan la diferencia y eventualmente tendríamos que merguearlas.

Comment: @devconcept Para evitar dañar al usuario y a la vez solucionar el problema de la etiqueta comodín, sin requerir trabajo manual es que planteo una posible respuesta utilizando una advertencia automática al respecto.

Comment: Actualmente hay 193 preguntas etiquetadas con python, 16 con ruby, 378 de java y **389** con javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada hay que dejar algo claro, que cuando un usuario pregunta por cual vía es la mejor como en la [primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7871/c%C3%B3mo-generar-ids-con-formato-en-django), se debe de manera obligada colocar el/los tag involucrado (Incluso si no lo están un moderador u otro usuario lo colocaran). Dificilmente en un futuro estos `tags` sean eliminado así la respuesta que tenga mas votos no use todas las tecnologías que tiene la pregunta, ya que, puede que en un futuro un usuario como tú interesado en `javascript` por ejemplo, le de otra posible solución de alto nivel con alguna otra tecnología que envuelvan a la pregunta.

Cuando leí esto:

> El problema que intento plantear es que la etiqueta javascript pierde
>   su sentido si simplemente significa "esto tiene que ver con la web".

Desde mi punto de vista eso no es asi, cuando estas trabajando en una aplicación, sitio web o como le quieras llamar, siempre hay varias tecnologías envueltas en esto, y puede que no sepas donde esta el problema exactamente y por eso debas poner código de cliente y del server. Que la solución no era del lado del cliente, lamentablemente el tag debe quedar ahí ya que si una persona pensó que el problema era por javascript y no fue así, otra lo pensara. ¿Cuando elminar el tag? Cuando no se pregunta nada con respecto al tag o no tiene código relacionado a esto. Lamentablemente en las 3 preguntas que colocas, en las 2 primeras no hay código pero de manera implícita esta javascript metido ahí (Incluso en la pregunta 2 la persona que pregunta quiere código de como acceder al indexdb), y en la última hay código.

Adicionalmente, cuando se ve un tag en una pregunta, quiere decir que el usuario busca una solución en cualquiera de estos. En cambio si solo vez en una pregunta código y tag de `jQuery` por ejemplo, y el usuario especifica que no quiere sentencia javascript ya la cosa cambia.

Lamentablemente en mi opinión eliminar el tag, es mas mal que un bien. Yo sigo la etiqueta javascript y no me he llevado ningún problema al momento de seguirla. Como dijo @Carlos Muñoz esto pasa con todos los lenguajes y en todos los sitios de la familia de Stack Exchange. Hay algunas excepciones de hacer un retag, pero en este caso no lo veo así.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez etiquetar un Javascript-nativo?
o bien Javascript para referirnos a javascript puro y duro y los otros framework-javascript

Comment: No es tanto la cuestión de los frameworks, sinó la cuestión de preguntas etiquetadas con javascript cuando el lenguaje no es el tema de la pregunta. (ahí intento aclarar el punto).

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, cada pregunta debería tener siempre una o dos etiquetas genéricas que encuadren el tema principal de la pregunta, y una única etiqueta más específica que indique claramente el tema concreto. Si el usuario no es capaz de acerta con las etiquetas, tal vez debería poder hacerlo algún moderador.

Señalar que las etiquetas, además de indicar tus **favoritas**, también puedes indicar las que quieres **ignorar**, las cuales aparecen difuminadas (o, si lo pones en preferencias, hacer que no aparezcan). De este modo es posible ignorar un framework javascript en concreto si no deseas que aparezcan junto con las etiquetas `javascript`.

Answer (score -2):

#### Crear una etiqueta `[desarrollo-web]`

> Desde mi punto de vista eso no es asi, cuando estas trabajando en una aplicación, sitio web o como le quieras llamar, siempre hay varias tecnologías envueltas en esto, y puede que no sepas donde esta el problema exactamente y por eso debas poner código de cliente y del server.

Podríamos crear una etiqueta `[desarrollo-web]` para estos casos.

> En mi opinión, cada pregunta debería tener siempre una o dos etiquetas genéricas que encuadren el tema principal de la pregunta, y una única etiqueta más específica que indique claramente el tema concreto.

Dicha etiqueta puede funcionar bien como etiqueta *generica*, pero a la vez es más específica que `[javascript]` para preguntas como las citadas.

> Crear otra etiqueta sólo crea otro problema ya que es poco probable que los usuarios entiendan la diferencia y eventualmente tendríamos que merguearlas.

Para evitar eso se podría agregar una advertencia al agregar la etiqueta javascript, recomendando las nuevas etiquetas.

> Las etiquetas de lenguaje de programación también sirven además para indicarle al syntax highlighter como debe formatear el código, por lo que está bien clasificar las preguntas como javascript y algún framework en específico.

Esta etiqueta también podría ser configurada para resaltar la sintaxis de javascript, css, html, etc.

Otras etiquetas que se me ocurren que podrían ser útiles son [manipulación-DOM] y [HTML5].

De esta manera la etiqueta [javascript] sigue existiendo (no propongo borrar la etiqueta), pero así se podría lograr que las preguntas sean más específicas.