# ¿Las preguntas relacionadas con Angular o Typescript están o no relacionadas con Javascript?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas

Un usuario de forma insistente y sistemática está realizando ediciones en las preguntas etiquetadas con [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), [angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) y [typescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) que *también* están etiquetadas con [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) eliminando la etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) en todas argumentando **'La pregunta no tiene que ver con Javascript'**.

Dado que Angular y AngularJS son frameworks de Javascript y que TypeScript es un subconjunto de Javascript pregunto: ¿Debo aceptar o rechazar las ediciones de estas preguntas que eliminen la etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)? ¿La etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) hace más fácil clasificar la pregunta, o es una etiqueta redundante o por el contrario sí está relacionada con las etiquetas principales?

---

Preguntas relacionadas a este caso:

- [Uso de routelink en el html base](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30079/uso-de-routelink-en-el-html-base) → [edición sugerida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/39319)
- [Observable dentro de un for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60781/observable-dentro-de-un-for) → [edición sugerida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/39310)
- [input component angular2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60878/input-component-angular2) → [edición sugerida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/39313)

Comment: Primero que nada angulajs-2.0 no existe en la vida real y _no debería_ existir esa etiqueta en [es.so]. Por otro lado, visto que podemos afirmar que todo el código javascript es código typescript válido, pero no podemos afirmar lo contrario, yo opino que es posible eliminar la etiqueta, aunque no podría afirmar que no están relacionados.

Comment: No veo las ediciones que mencionaste. ¿Podrías poner algunos ejemplos? como para tener mejor contexto. gracias!

Comment: Si las etiquetas se usan para dar visibilidad a la pregunta y siendo muchos mas usuarios los que leen [javascript] que cualquiera de las otras dos. parece tener sentido etiquetarlas asi.  ver.. [¿Cómo podemos arreglar el tag javascript?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/551/25)

Answer (score 2):

Yo pienso que el tag javascript, estaría sobrando si:

- El código que usted está creando, (no el transpilador) *"typescript transpiler"*, no tiene codigo específico de JS, por ejemplo:

```js
//= require services/heroes-service
//= require directives/hero-detail-component

var HeroesComponent = ng.core.Component({
    properties: ['model'],
    directives: [HeroDetailComponent],    
    template: "<h2>My Heroes</h2> \
                <ul class='heroes'> \
                  <li *ngFor='#hero of heroes_list' [class.selected]='hero === selectedHero' (click)='onSelect(hero)'> \
                     <span class='badge'>{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} \
                  </li> \
                </ul> \
                <div *ngIf='selectedHero'> \
                  <h2> \
                    {{selectedHero.name | uppercase}} is my hero \
                  </h2> \
                  <button (click)='gotoDetail()'>View Details</button> \
                </div>"
}).Class({
    constructor: [
      HeroService, ng.router.Router, ng.http.Http, function(heroService, router, http) {
        this._heroService = heroService;
        this._router = router;
        this._http = http;
      }
    ],
    ngOnInit: function() { this.getHeroes() },
    onSelect: function(hero) { this.selectedHero = hero },
    gotoDetail: function() { this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.selectedHero.id }]); },
    getHeroes: function() {
      //we get the list from mock-heroes.js
      //this._heroService.getHeroes.then(heroes => this.heroes_list = heroes);

      //we get the list from the server
      this._heroService.getHeroes(this._http).subscribe(heroes => this.heroes_list = heroes);
    }
});
```

Para una pregunta con un código que pueda ser similar al anterior, NO estaria de más el tag de javascript, es más, creo que hasta sería recomendable, pero tomando como ejemplo el anterior código, si la pregunta en cuestión cuenta con un código mas parecido al siguiente:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {Hero} from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  templateUrl: 'app/heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/heroes.component.css'],
  directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  public heroes: Hero[];
  public selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private _heroService: HeroService, private _router: Router) { }

  getHeroes() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  gotoDetail() {
    this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.selectedHero.id }]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Pienso, en este caso el tag oportuno es solamente el de typescript, obviamente con el de angular, si piensa que su error o duda está relacionada con el framework.

---

Pienso que el tag javascript, NO estaría sobrando si:

- Hace uso de librerías de terceros o no, las cuales, son integramente en JS, o por lo menos y gran mayoria, y piensa que el error tiene relación con el uso de esa librería al tratar de usarla en un código de TS.

---

Cosas a parte. El tag de `angularjs-2.0` o cualquier variante, no es que no exista y la gente se lo inventara, es que en la transición o mientras estaba creándose, lo que muchos conocen como `angular2`, `angular4.0.1`, ect, no es más que `angular`, si de mí dependiera dejaría el tag `angularjs-1.x` para todo lo relacionado con el framework antes de su reconstrucción, y para despues de esta, *"cuando se centró en TS, etc."*, con un tag limpio solo `angular`, porque si se sigue añadiendo *angular2*, *angular4*, *angular4.0.1*, quien sabe cuántos tag habrá al respecto en un futuro.

... Volviendo. Muchos lo llamaban así incluso es muy probable que el mismo equipo de desarrollo de Angular lo nombrara así en algun punto, no he podido ver conversaciones entre ellos, pero pude leer cómo lo citaba antes en [ng-learn](http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/AngularJS-2-Status-Preview/) por ejemplo:

- AngularJS team has been busy working on AngularJS 2.0.
- What is AngularJS 2.0 all about?
- ...team has queued for AngularJS 2.0.

**Aclaración final: No soy ningún experto en Angular.**

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con que un framework puede o no estar etiquetado con el lenguaje de acuerdo al código (a la pregunta en sí)